# SQL query based on two columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a quite large products table and I need some smart solution to find out which products are (in woocommerce terms) Simple, Variable, and Variation.

In the example table below, ids 6 and 7 are Simple products (they don't have children), 1 and 4 are Variable products (they have children), and 2,3,5 are Variations (they are children).

| id | item_id | parent_id | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa | aaa | ... |
| 2 | aaa-1 | aaa | ... |
| 3 | aaa-2 | aaa | ... |
| 4 | bbb | bbb | ... |
| 5 | bbb-1 | bbb | ... |
| 6 | ccc | ccc | ... |
| 7 | ddd | ddd | ... |

My goal is to first get Simple products, then get Variable products and import them and lastly get Variations and import them to the existing parent Variable products.

I have a solution for Simple products:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM $table_name
    WHERE item_id = parent_id
    GROUP BY parent_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS ONLY_ONCE
```

I've tried similar for the Variable products (`count(*) > 1`), but it doesn't work...

For Variation I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM $table_name 
WHERE item_id != parent_id
```

1. Simple products - select all where item_id is equal with parent_id, and parent_id occurs only once.
2. Variable products - select all where item_id is equal with parent_id and parent_id occurs more than once.
3. Variation - select all where item_id and parent_id are not equal.

How could I write those three queries, especially the second one? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                          FROM test t2
                          WHERE t2.parent_id = t1.item_id
                            AND t2.item_id <> t2.parent_id )
            THEN 'Variable'
            WHEN NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                              FROM test t3
                              WHERE t3.parent_id = t1.item_id )
            THEN 'Variation'
            ELSE 'Simple'
            END Category
FROM test t1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3215cbb3febbdbc4132ee00aac2ad8e

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This code does work, but it isn't efficient enough, it takes too long to process (200+ seconds), even though I select only three columns.
I have a table (~50MB) with 16k  rows and 35 columns.

Comment: @Marin Create four indices. Unique indices by `(item_id)`, `(item_id, parent_id)` and `(parent_id, item_id)`, and an index by `(parent_id)`. Test the speed. If they improve then look at the query execution plan and drop the indices which are not used. Remember - if the data array changes a lot then optimal indices pack may alter.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this as a combination of SQL queries and php code.

At first I would get all parents (variable products) and fetch the results. In PHP then loop through the results and use the parents id as parameter for the next query.

Comment: This makes no sense. Data processing which may be performed on DBMS must be performed on DBMS.